# Porque o vuejs diz que essa função não existe? se esta funcionando ok

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tenho o seguinte codigo abaixo a função openDados(), ela funciona mais dentro do contexto de retorno da chamada socket não funciona porque..

lembro de ver algo semelhando tipo this = this algo do tipo mais não lembro aonde foi.... segue o codigo para os feras ajudar...

```
mounted () {
   this.openDados() // aqui funciona funciona
   this.socket.emit('find-user', {
      userid: this.id
    }, function (data) {
      this.openDados() // está func que não funciona
      console.log(data)
      if (data.length <= 0) {
        console.log('entrou aqui') // teste e chega aqui
      } else {
        const payload2 = {
          id: data.userid,
          name: data.name,
          display: data.display,
          descript: data.descript,
          avatar: data.avatar
        }
        this.USER(payload2)
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations('config', ['SET_DISPLAY_LEFT']),
    ...mapMutations('user', ['USER']),
    mostrarImagem (imagem) {
      if (imagem !== null) {
        return process.env.API_S3 + '/wbynet/' + imagem
      } else {
        return 'statics/boy-avatar.png'
      }
    },
    openDados () {
      this.openDadosConf = true
    },
```

o erro que recebo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto acontece porque o this dentro de socket é outro contexto. O método que você chama pertence ao "this" externo. Desta forma, antes de chamar "this.socket...", crie algo como:

```
const self = this;
```

Então, dentro do socket você chama:

```
self.openData();
```

E pra tudo o mais que se referir ao "this" externo. Faça o teste e diga se resolveu. Sucesso pra voce;!

Comment: Obrigado, Salvo !!! Gratidão